# How to check BIOS Settings from Terminal (CentOS 7)?

Tags: centos, command-line, terminal, bios

I am trying to verify three BIOS settings on remote Linux machines (Dell OptiPlex 3090) with CentOS 7 on them. I want to check AC Recovery is Enabled, Wake on LAN, and Block Sleep.
I've tried multiple things so far:

- `dmidecode` This just seems to show hardware specific information. Not any settings
- `biosdecode` Same reason ^
- `hwinfo` Same Reason ^
- `ethtool` Just to check if WOL was enabled on the eth interface but it always says its disabled even though BIOS says its enabled so that doesn't seem very reliable

I installed [fwupd](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd) as well but was unable to get it to work properly.

- Installing it with `yum` would only yield me an outdated version (1.0.9 or something).
- Installing with `snap` I kept running into  `Run install hook of "fwupd" snap if present (run hook "install" error` whenever I tried installing it ([its currently an open bug](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/5122))
- I finally installed it with `flatpak` and it gave me the most updated version (1.8.9) but when I try running `flatpak run org.freedesktop.fwupd get-bios-settings` (tried with sudo as well) I get this error with no output:

  `WARNING: This package has not been validated, it may not work properly. This system doesn't support firmware settings`

So I added `OverrideESPMountPoint=/efi` to the `uefi_capsule.conf` file ([outlined here](https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:esp-not-found)) and got this error

```
 15:45:40.358 F                                                                                                                                                          uEngine migrating OverrideESPMountPoint=/efi to EspLocation
    Failed to create file “/app/etc/fwupd/daemon.conf.2KS4Y1”: Read-only file system
```

So I tried `chmod g-or /app/etc/fwupd/daemon.conf` but that didn't change anything.

So any other options would be much appreciated to just check the three settings!

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS interface is specific to each hardware vendor. There is no API for accessing settings from the OS and so no general method to access settings from the cli. Some manufacturers have provided packages to interface with their implementations but these are generally for Windows systems. HPE has an interface to their iLO on servers but that touches only some of the BIOS.

If you think about it, if a malicious user got root privileges and the BIOS was accessible from the cli, then hardware settings could be changed with unpredictable results.

Comment: Would you be able to look at fwupd? Their Wiki in particular seems to allow access to view BIOS settings https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/blob/main/docs/bios-settings.md

Comment: @Student1860 The fwupd tutorial includes the line `Although it would be a wonderful world if we could update all hardware using a standard shared protocol this is not the universe we live in.` Both `DFU` and `UpdateCapsule` are supported but DFU seems to be limited to iPhones and UpdateCapsule is for UEFI. Doesn't help in general for desktop/server BIOS settings. I'm having difficulty building the package so I'll have to get back to you later on if it works on my servers.

Comment: @Student1860 I'm running into a dependency hell. After downloading `fwupd`, I need to install a current version of `meson`, then a current version of `ninja`, and then I'm still hit with an error that `gobject-introspection-1.0` is not found. I am reluctant to keep following this chain of installs to get an application working when the app's release notes say that it does not work in many cases.

Comment: Yeah I spent a full day on this as you can see from my post, I ended up having to install it with flatpak.